# Finding basis to fit given criteria

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $D\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}_3(R)\to\mathcal{P}_2(R))$ is the Differentiation map defined by $Dp = p\prime$. There exists a basis for $\mathcal{P}_3(R)$ and $\mathcal{P}_2(R)$ such that the matrix of $D$ with respect to theses matrices is as follows
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
**Proof.** Let $\frac{x^3}{3},\frac{x^2}{2},x,1$ be the required basis for $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbf{R})$ and $x^2,x,1$ be the required basis for $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Now let $w = \alpha_3 x^3+\alpha_2 x^2+\alpha_1 x+\alpha_0$ be an arbitrary polynomial in $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbf{R})$, restating as a linear combination of our basis vectors we have

$w = 3\alpha_3(\frac{x^3}{3})+2\alpha_2(\frac{x^2}{2})+\alpha_1 x+\alpha_0$ consequently we have the resulting matrix equation.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  3\alpha_3\\
  2\alpha_2\\
  \alpha_1\\
  0
\end{pmatrix}
 =
\begin{pmatrix}
  3\alpha_3\\
  2\alpha_2\\
  \alpha_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
evidently $\frac{d}{dx}(w) = 3\alpha_3 x^2+2\alpha_2 x+\alpha_1$ thus the given matrix does indeed correspond to our choice of basis for $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbf{R})$ and $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbf{R})$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: This theorem is a special case of a more general result for linear transformations and their matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is correct. My approach would have been the following,

Let the basis for $\mathcal{P}_3(R)$ be $a_1 = \frac{x^3}{3}, a_2 = \frac{x^2}{2}, a_3 = x, a_4 = 1$ and the basis for $\mathcal{P}_2(R)$ be $b_1 = x^2, b_2 = x, b_3 = 1$. Now, I will show that the Differentiation map from $\mathcal{P}_3(R)$ to $\mathcal{P}_2(R)$ with the above basis has the matrix defined in the statement of the theorem.

$$\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \frac{x^3}{3} = x^2 = b_1$$

$$\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \frac{x^2}{2} = x = b_2$$

$$\frac{\partial a_3}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} x = 1 = b_3$$

$$\frac{\partial a_4}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial 1} \frac{x^3}{3} = 0$$

Therefore, the column of the matrix corresponding to the Differentiation map will be,

$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Some further notes:

$$
C(D^T) = span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$

$$
N(D) = span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$

$$
C(D) = span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$

So, any input $y$ to this matrix can be split into $y_r$ and $y_n$ where $y_r$ is the component in row space which comprises of all polynomials in $\mathcal{P}_3(R)$ with zero as the constant term and $y_n$ is the component in null space which comprises of all polynomials in $\mathcal{P}_3(R)$ with only constant term. On multiplying the above matrix to $y$, $Dy = Dy_r + Dy_n$, the row space component maps to an element in the column space which comprises of all polynomials in $\mathcal{P}_2(R)$ and the null space component maps to $0$.